# Google AppEngine crash saying "Fatal Error No deploy command"

Tags: macos, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

When I tried to deploy a web site, Google AppEngine crash saying

```
Fatal Error No deploy command(installation problem?)
```

I tried to find the google_appengine directory and I found /usr/local/google_appengine.old directory but I could not find any google_appengine directory. (I checked `/usr/local` and `/usr/local/bin` and a few. )

When I tried to make symlinks, it generate no errors, but it doesn't seem create google_appengine directory.

And problem is AppEngine Launcher just crash and I have no idea to watch error log.

My Environment :

Mac OSX 10.10.3, Python 2.7.9, GoogleAppEngineLauncher-1.9.21(Python)

Answer (score 0):

Go through the installation procedure again, to ensure the `gae-python` component is properly installed and gets added to your shell environment.

From https://console.developers.google.com/start/appengine :

> Download and install Google Cloud SDK by running the following command
>   in your shell or Terminal:
>
> ```
> curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com/ | bash
> ```
>
> Follow the prompts to install the Python and PHP App Engine package.
>
> Restart your shell or Terminal to pick up environment changes.
>
> ```
> exec -l $SHELL
> ```
>
> Sign in to Google Cloud Platform using this command:
>
> ```
> gcloud auth login
> ```
>
> Install the App Engine package for Python using this command:
>
> ```
> gcloud components update gae-python
> ```

Comment: Thank you! I think I have to set Python Path. Is it okay to set just "/usr/local/bin/python" ? or should I set gae-python path? Actually I don't know where gae-python is installed...

Comment: If your `python` is located there, it's ok to use that. On my linux system my google-cloud-sdk is located in my home folder, i.e `~/google-cloud-sdk/`, so I have the following in my `.zshrc`: `source /home/myuser/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc` There is something similar here for mac(both zsh and bash): http://stackoverflow.com/q/21236855/2295256